# How do I change sass property dynamically when element is focused?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I have an Input type search and a div just below it.
I want to change the color of the div from blue to red when the search box is focused.

my Div

```
  <div id="demo-2">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search By Title, Author" />
    <div class="autocomplete">
      hello
    </div>
  </div>
```

the classes I have applied

```
#demo-2 input[type="search"]:focus {
  width: 275px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: auto;
}

.autocomplete {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 350px;
  width: 275px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  z-index: -50;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

My requirement is that the background-color of class autocomplete should change from blue to red when the search is focused without using any javascript.

Tried below code but didn't work

```
#demo-2 input[type="search"]:focus {
  width: 275px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: auto;

  .autocomplete {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [adjacent sibling combinator (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) or the [general sibling combinator (~)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

```
#demo-2 input[type="search"]:focus {
  width: 275px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: auto;

  ~ .autocomplete {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  You the Man.

Comment: Hey, can you explain a little bit more as to why my code didn't work and what if I want to change the property of a class which is not a sibling but somewhere else in the HTML?

Comment: Your code didn't work because `.autocomplete` is not a child of the focused input, which is what your version of the code was trying to target. It depends where in the HTML you want your other element to be. If this is the descendant of a sibling, then you can use a similar thing, `input:focus ~ .sibling .your-element`. If it is not, I am afraid you will not be able to achieve this using CSS only and will have to add some JS, as CSS does not have a selector to target the parent element (yet)

Comment: However, if your input is the only focusable element in one of the ancestors, and you want to select a sibling (or one of its descendants) of that ancestor element, you could use [:focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within): `#demo-2:focus-within ~ .demo-sibling .target { background: red; }`

Comment: Warning: `focus-within` is not supported on Edge.

Comment: Makes sense, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of div use label and make the label block for example

```css
input{
  &:focus{
    & ~ label{
      background-color:red;
    }
  }
}

label{
  display:block;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  padding:.5rem;
  margin-top:1rem;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="user" autocomplete="off">
<label for="user">Username</label>
```